# Use of inintialized value $ in concatenation (.) Perl

Tags: perl

```
use warnings;

$a = 5; 
$c = 3;
$i;
$x = time();
$m = 32;
$caracter_aleatorio;
@caracteres = (A..Z);
print "Ingrese la cantidad de letras que desea generar=> ";
$n = <STDIN>; 

sub generadorMultiplicativo{  
        $numAleatorio = ((($a*$x) + $c) % $m);  
        $x = $numAleatorio;
}

for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++){   
      &generadorMultiplicativo();
      $caracter_aleatorio = $caracteres[$numAleatorio];
        if($numAleatorio == 0){
       $numAleatorio++;
       }
    if($numAleatorio > 26){
       $numAleatorio = $numAleatorio - 5;
    }

     print"Letra #$i = $caracter_aleatorio\n";  
} 
<>;
```

I know this warning is when the variable doesn't have a value, but I´ve tried everything but it´s the same, it´s a generator of "random" letters.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Always `use strict` when writing new code.
2. Uninitialized warnings means that your `$caracter_aleatorio` variable is undefined, so you should set a default.  Undefined variables are usually a sign of buggy code.
3. Declare your variables using `my`
4. One-letter variables should be avoided for maintenance / readability reasons.
5. No-longer need to call functions with `&foo()` notation, `foo()` is fine.
6. Use quotes around A and Z to generate the range.

Here is an updated version of your code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = 5;
my $c = 3;
my $i;
my $x = time();
my $m = 32;
my $caracter_aleatorio;
my $numAleatorio;
my @caracteres = ('A'..'Z');
print "Ingrese la cantidad de letras que desea generar=> ";
my $n = <STDIN>;

sub generadorMultiplicativo{
    $numAleatorio = ((($a*$x) + $c) % $m);
    $x = $numAleatorio;
}

for( $i=1; $i<=$n; $i++ ) {
    generadorMultiplicativo();
    $caracter_aleatorio = $caracteres[$numAleatorio] || 'unknown';
    if($numAleatorio == 0){
        $numAleatorio++;
    }
    if($numAleatorio > 26){
        $numAleatorio = $numAleatorio - 5;
    }

    print"Letra #$i = $caracter_aleatorio\n";
}
```

Suggestions to improve further:

1. Learn how to accept/return parameters from subroutines.  [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html)
2. Input validation, what if I pass in 'abc' instead of 123, numeric vs string comparison operators ( `<=` vs `lt`, `==` vs `eq`, `>=` vs `gt`, etc. ).
3. Write comments to show high level intent of your code.
4. Provide a usage/help message to show a new user how to use your script.
5. The perl documentation is excellent, have a read through [perldoc perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html)

Answer (score 1):

To see the issue, after you call generadorMultiplicativo(); you can do some debug printing of $numAleatorio to see that it sometimes goes higher than you intend. That is, it can be greater than 25.

```
print "DEBUG: $numAleatorio of $#caracteres\n";
```

Your method tries to fix these out of bounds values, but you have some issues:

1. 26 as the upper limit instead of 25
2. You subtract 5 if above upper bound but sometimes you are more than 5 above upper bound.
3. Your pseudorandom number generator is generating values too high.

Recommended rewrite:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @caracteres = ('A'..'Z');
print "Ingres la cantidad de letras que desea generar=> ";
while(my $n = <STDIN>) {
  last unless $n =~ /^[0-9]+$/; # Check upper limit?
  for (1.. $n) {
    print "Letras #%d = %s\n", $_, $caracteres[int(rand(26))];
  }
}
```

Does almost the same thing except you can keep asking for more random chars. Just enter non-digit to exit.

First post/answer and typed on my phone so please forgive my mistakes!